# How to build a .ipa file in xcode

Tags: ios, build, ipa

Actually I want to build a .ipa file for installing that on a iphone deveice.

when I want to build I get this error:

*There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have register it.*

But I don't want to register any device. I want to install to any device.

Comment: You need to register at least one device in your developer account before you can build an ipa.  In order to install that ipa on a device, the device needs to be included in the developer account. You cannot create a build that can install on *any* device. To do that you will need to use TestFlight or release via the app store.

Comment: So if I want to distribute my app in app store, I won't need to register a device. right?

Comment: You will need to register one device otherwise you cannot create the provisioning profile necessary to create the build you submit to the store. Really, though, you need to test your app on a physical device. The simulator is not a substitute for real device testing.

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate answer is: **if you want to install to any device, your app needs to be published on the App Store**

More detailed answer:

There are 4 ways you can install the app on the device:

1. Personal device, using your personal team account (no cost)
2. You can add up to 100 devices to your Apple Development Team account each year. This way you can ask your friend for their device identifier, register it and you can share your work to them for example, using [Diawi](https://www.diawi.com/). The Apple Developer account costs $100/year
3. You can apply for an Enterprise Account - this solution is more costly but allows you to export your app to unlimited amount of devices. The catch? They will need to accept an enterprise certificate before they can use the application.
4. BetaFlight - you can allow external testers to sign-up for beta testing of your app (or you can invite them). This solution does not require you to collect the identifiers, but the app itself needs to go through App Review before it is available to testers for a limited time.